# Get Old Objects, Update, and then return old objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an `APIView` that looks like this:

```
class GetNotifications(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        notifications = Notification.objects.select_related().filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-created_at")
        Notification.objects.select_for_update().filter(is_read=False, user=self.request.user).update(is_read=True)
        return notifications
```

What I'm trying to do is get all notifications that the user has. These include notifications that have been read and that have been not read yet (hence the is_read field). I'd like to return both the `is_read` and the not `is_read` notifications.Once those objects are received then an update will happen to change the not read notifications to is read. What this means is that any user who accesses this API through the site will mean that they've read their notifications so we can set `is_read=True`...however, my current code returns the objects after updating them. I want to return the old objects prior to updating hence me assigning notifications to the old objects before updating. I believe this is due to lazy loading on Django's part. Is there a way/better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however, my current code returns the objects after updating them. I want to return the old objects prior to updating hence me assigning notifications to the old objects before updating. I believe this is due to lazy loading on Django's part. Is there a way/better way to solve this?

It will still return the *updated* objects, since the query will, if ever, be evaluated *after* the update, and hence at that time `is_read` will already be set to `True`.

You should "materialize" the queryset, so forcing to load it into memory. For example by calling `list(…)` on it:

```
class GetNotifications(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        notifications = (
            Notification.objects.select_related()
            .filter(user=self.request.user)
            .order_by('-created_at')
        )
        list(notifications)
        Notification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).update(is_read=True)
        return notifications
```

Comment: Just wondering, would this affect performance in anyway?

Comment: @user2896120: if you have to load in the notifications anyway, it will only result in one query, so no extra database queries no.